# Elasticsearch : Term frequency vs FieldNorm

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I am new to elasticsearch and I am trying to understand the scoring algorithm.

According to this [link](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html), ES uses the **term frequency** which is "the square root of the number of times the term appears in the document." and the **field-length norm** which is the "inverse square root of the number of terms in the field".

So basically, if I search for the word "ticket" in the field "title" of my mapping, having 1 occurrence of "ticket" in a 4-words title is equivalent  to having 2 occurrences of "ticket" in an 8-words title.

So far it does not shock me, but with this formula, the weight given for a title "ticket", will be also the same weight given for a title "ticket ticket", and the same for a title "ticket ticket ticket"....

I know this scenario is quite unlikely, but I am just trying to understand the logic behind.

For me, the term frequency should be more important than the field length.

Did I miss something ?  Or do you think the formula used by ES makes sense ?

Comment: Here weight for "ticket ticket" and "Train ticket" wont be the same. That is the point.

Comment: I get that. All I am saying why not for example using directly the term frequency instead of its square root. So the weight for "ticket" will be 1, for "ticket ticket" will be square root of 2 and the wight for "train ticket " will be 1/(square root of 2). This makes more sense to me.

Comment: For me both "Ticket" and "ticket ticket ticket" should looks same and given same priority. Idea of field normalization is to see how important that token is for this context. So if this is all the token there is , then the importance is the max.